# How to build GeoExplorer on Windows

Tags: geoserver, boundless-suite, geoexplorer

I am trying to utilize GeoExplorer (made by OpenGeo) to browse data provided by GeoServer.

So far, I have downloaded source code from https://github.com/opengeo/GeoExplorer. Some instructions I found mention Ant and Git software to build app., but I can't make it work.

Could somebody suggest me how to set up GeoExplorer (non-Suite) on Windows? If you could ouline the required steps, that  would be great.
Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Responded in GetSatisfaction [1]. If you could avoid posting the same question simultaneously to multiple forms it would be appreciated. Thanks.

[1] http://getsatisfaction.com/opengeo/topics/how_to_build_geoexplorer_out_of_suite_on_windows

Answer (score 2):

The instructions at the GeoExplorer's [README.MD](https://github.com/opengeo/GeoExplorer/blob/master/README.md) work fine. You'd have to set up your PC first though. The guide assumes that you already have Ant and Git running. To comply with it:

1. **Install Ant.** Easiest way to install And would be to use [WinAnt](http://code.google.com/p/winant/). Just get the installer from their site and run it.
2. **Install git.** Get the [Git for windows](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list) installer and run it. Github has a tutorial on [setting up git](http://help.github.com/win-set-up-git/). I suggest you read it.

Once you're done installing, the instructions on the guide should work. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Install Java, Git, Ant and Maven are not enough, I've succeed build that geoexplorer.war by using some git url change. Use the branch 4.1 and build using "mvn install" don't forget to build dependancies first.

1. I assume you have installed **[Git](http://git-scm.com/download/win)**, **[Ant](http://code.google.com/p/winant/)**, **[JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)** (**NOT JRE!!**), and **[Maven](http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi)**.
2. Clone it, type this in youre command prompt (run it twice to make sure no file missing)

   > git clone https://github.com/boundlessgeo/suite.git -b r4.1
3. You will start to clone it on youre PC. After it finish cloning, enter the directory using this command :

   > cd suite
4. Build Dependencies. When build dependencies make sure you have good internet connection, I need to build it twice because of disconected internet connection, type this command :

   > git submodule update --init --recursive
5. Build Geoexplorer.war, type this command :

   > mvn install
6. Enjoy..
7. Still not working or to lazy to fix it? just download this [geoexplorer.zip](http://www.mediafire.com/download/1z9odjxtz4qfdk8/geoexplorer.zip) and extract it in your *webapps* folder

*Work as it was tested on July 14th 2014*

Comment: these steps are no longer working due to a missing dependency - thanks for posting the zip